# Unity - Scroll Rect?

Tags: button, unity-game-engine, uiscrollview, scrollrect

I have this problem. I'm using a scroll rect to display a series of buttons, but I would make sure that as soon as the buttons (with the scroll rect), come out of a certain area (bounded by a panel), become invisible.
to explain it better in the pictures. I would like the visible part of the list of buttons to stop where there is the black arrow, and then I would delete the part where I drew the red waves

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to mathf.clamp the area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use UI Mask to hide the elements when they are out of parent's bounds. [Here's a good tutorial about it.](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-mask)